Ping from dummy interface
I want to test NAT table using dummy interface. I have enp1s0 interface connected to internet and have configured NAT table to MASQUERADE packets as shown below.
random@debian:~$ ip addr
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
        inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 52:54:00:4d:63:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 192.168.122.10/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global enp1s0
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe4d:63c0/64 scope link 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    3: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 5e:81:f3:78:47:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 10.0.0.10/24 scope global dummy0
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 fe80::5c81:f3ff:fe78:47c0/64 scope link 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

random@debian:~$ ip route
default via 192.168.122.1 dev enp1s0 onlink 
10.0.0.0/24 dev dummy0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.10 
192.168.122.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.10

random@debian:~$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

random@debian:~$ lsmod | grep dummy
dummy                  16384  0

random@debian:~$ ipt
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

random@debian:~$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o enp1s0

random@debian:~$ ipt -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  any    enp1s0  10.0.0.0/24          anywhere 

With these ip configuration. Testing with ping
random@debian:~$ ping -I 10.0.0.10 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 10.0.0.10 : 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=114 time=28.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=114 time=30.9 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 28.302/29.583/30.865/1.281 ms

random@debian:~$ ping -I dummy0 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 10.0.0.10 dummy0: 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4095ms
      

Sending packets through dummy interface does not work. Packets can be seen in dummy interface dummy0 but are not forwarded to enp1s0 as observed using wireshark.

Because it makes no sense to use dummy in such case. Use a netns and a veth pair, if you have to "test". (To be frank, I have no idea why you don't test with the "actual thing".)

With netns and a veth pair it works. I just wanted to understand why it does not work with this configuration. Keeping every thing same and replacing dummy with bridge also does not work.

There is no such thing as "the other end" (except maybe a void) with a dummy interface. In other words, it's not really different from lo, except one would usually configure an address from a block other than the loopback one (127.0.0.0/8). (To be frank, I'm not sure if under any circumstances one could literally need a dummy interface these days. It seems to me that it exists for more of historical reasons.)
Anyway, the real problem here isn't exactly about dummy, but about -I in ping. I've seen a lot of people have similar misunderstanding, but I could only barely see / guess where it comes from, so I can only hope that the following explanation could help you get out of it:

If interface is an interface name, it sets source interface to specified interface.

The fact that you can use an interface as a "source interface" does NOT mean that you can emulate / simulate a "source host" like when you ping from a different netns. The sentence here really just means that "ignore routes that has a different interface (dev)", or in other words, "make (sure) the traffics egress via only this interface no matter what". (It seems that if the destination is not covered by any route of that interface, the destination would be considered "onlink".)
In other words, "source interface" does NOT mean "ingress interface".
So when you use -I on a dummy interface, the only destination that could make sense would be the IP configured on the dummy itself, which would result in loopback traffics. Such traffics would obviously never egress out of the host via another interface like enp1s0. (Apparently loopback traffics can't even be DNAT'd in PREROUTING.) Traffics destined at e.g. 8.8.8.8 would not actually be going anywhere (but a void).
(NOTE: In fact, precisely speaking loopback traffics does not egress out of the host at all, so I suppose in at least some sense, you may consider it an "exception" in -I "made possible" with the corresponding local route, because the dummy interface is still its route interface, even when it causes the traffics to be looped back and "ingress" the host via lo.)
With that said, an SNAT (not MASQUERADE) rule that matches with only (i.e. no -o enp1s0) a source address (block) (e.g. -s 10.0.0.0/24) would "work" for such loopback traffics. It's just I can't see what could be the point in performing such "test".
To "test" a MASQUERADE rule, you would need traffics that egress via the specific interface (e.g. enp1s0). Therefore, you would need (well, somewhat; see the last section) another "host" to be the "source host", which would form a network with this host and therefore have a source IP from some IP subnet that is different from the one used by the network that the interface (e.g. enp1s0) is attached to, and hence needs to be masqueraded (if that "other side" has no return route for this subnet).
And these days the easiest way to "create" a network / (network-wise) host is netns + veth pair.

Note that -I works very differently when you use an IP address instead of an interface as the argument.

If interface is an address, it sets source address to specified interface address.

AFAIK in this case it does not affect route decision. Basically it just sets the source IP address of the traffics beforehand, instead of leaving it unset and letting the system pick one for it based on / after the route decision.
Therefore, a MASQUERADE rule is actually necessary and would "work" for:
ping -I 10.0.0.10 8.8.8.8

But then the question is, what does it even mean when you are not testing with the actual thing (I'm NOT even talking about a "testing netns") that the MASQUERADE rule is ultimately supposed to serve?

Thank you for your response.
The fact that you can use an interface as a "source interface" does NOT mean that you can emulate / simulate a "source host" like when you ping from a different netns.
This statement cleared my confusion. Its seems I misunderstood how routing decision is made when using ping -I. I thought if i specify interface with -I, the packets will still end up at enp1s0 following the route table.
